# what is the java equivalent of <?,?> in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

here is my method

`void login(Event<?, ?> event);`
I am wondering how it should be in Kotlin

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin wildcard operator is `*`. It instructs the compiler that it is unknown but once it got known there will be no other object of another type.

Replacement of

**Java -> Kotlin**

- `<?>` -> `<*>`
- `Object` -> `Any?`
- `<? extends A>` -> `<out A?>`
- `<? super A>` -> `<in A?>`

> Here question mark (`?`) above means the field can be nullable, in java null and non-null are same but in Kotlin to accept null we need to explicitly mark it nullable.

Answer (score 4):

```
fun login(event: Event<*, *>?)
```

***Star projection***, denoted by the **`*`** character. Sometimes you want to say that you know nothing about the type argument, but still want to use it in a safe way. The safe way here is to define such a projection of the **GENERIC TYPE**.

Read official guideline about [**`Star-projection`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) Kotlin syntax.